# Auto-Scaling Ejabberd Cluster in Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, erlang, ejabberd, autoscaling

I have an Ejabberd cluster (v17.07 with Erlang/OTP 18) running on AWS EKS. We have enabled autoscaling based on CPU usage of the nodes.

But whenever the cluster scales up or down, other nodes in the cluster becomes unhealthy/not-ready for some time (~ 3 to 4 mins) and then becomes healthy/ready again.
This happens whenever any new node is added or any node is removed from the cluster.

As per the official documentation (https://docs.ejabberd.im/admin/guide/clustering),

while adding a node:

> This enables ejabberd's internal replications to be launched across all nodes so new nodes can start receiving messages from other nodes and be registered in the routing tables.

and while removing a node:

> To remove a node from the cluster, it just needs to be shut down. There is no specific delay for the cluster to figure out that the node is gone, the node is immediately removed from other router entries. All clients directly connected to the stopped node are disconnected, and should reconnect to other nodes.

Is this the reason why the nodes becomes unhealthy?

My hypothesis is that whenever nodes are added/removed from the cluster, it needs to perform some kind of rebalancing which is causing the nodes to go unhealthy temporarily. But I couldn't find any documentation/reference supporting it.

Has anyone has faced this issue or have any idea why this might be happening?

Comment: You should check how the health is defined: listening in port 5222? replying to "ejabberdctl status"?... You could also check what do those nodes show in their logs during those 4 startup minutes